# POST Request with Form Data Only Working for Current Year

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm attempting to send form data to get the information on bills for each year. Everything works as expected for 2019 however if I change the form data "ctl00$rilinContent$cbYear" to a prior year it just returns the default search page (which defaults to 2019 as the year) and thus gives no information to collect.

I attempted using "__EVENTTARGET" to change the year but didn't have any success, Thanks for any help you may be able to provide.

### Sample Code

```
import requests

default_data = {'__EVENTTARGET': '',
            '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
            '__LASTFOCUS': '',
            '__VIEWSTATE': 'PZZDS...', #(long string)
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 'B3C16737',
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': 'kp03y...', #(long string)
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbYear': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$txtReport': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbCommittee': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$comm': 'cbxIn',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbCategory': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbSponsor': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbxPrime': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$txtBills': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbxSortNumeric': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$txtBillFrom': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$txtBillTo': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbAction': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbxLastAction': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cmdReport': 'Enter',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$hfQuery': ''}

url = "http://status.rilin.state.ri.us/"
data = default_data

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"}

data['ctl00$rilinContent$cbYear'] = '2019'
data['ctl00$rilinContent$cbCategory'] = '307'

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers).text

# simple test
string = 'Legislative Status Report'
string in r
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the page does an initial update via POST for year then subsequently for marriage. The following can be simplified I'm sure but seems to work

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

default_data = {'__EVENTTARGET': '',
            '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
            '__LASTFOCUS': '',
            '__VIEWSTATE': '', 
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 'B3C16737',
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbYear': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$txtReport': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbCommittee': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$comm': 'cbxIn',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbCategory': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbSponsor': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbxPrime': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$txtBills': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbxSortNumeric': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$txtBillFrom': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$txtBillTo': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbAction': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cbxLastAction': '',
            'ctl00$rilinContent$cmdReport': '', #'Enter'
            'ctl00$rilinContent$hfQuery': ''}

url = "http://status.rilin.state.ri.us/"
data = default_data

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

data['ctl00$rilinContent$cbYear'] = 2017

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    vs = soup.select_one('#__VIEWSTATE')['value']
    ev = soup.select_one('#__EVENTVALIDATION')['value']
    data['__VIEWSTATE'] = vs
    data['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = ev
    r = s.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    vs = soup.select_one('#__VIEWSTATE')['value']
    ev = soup.select_one('#__EVENTVALIDATION')['value']
    data['ctl00$rilinContent$cbCategory'] = 307
    data['__VIEWSTATE'] = vs
    data['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = ev
    data['ctl00$rilinContent$cmdReport'] = 'Enter'
    r = s.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    print(soup)
```

Comment: Yep, this is the very logic the script should be built upon. You can make it within 20 lines, though. Ain't that slightly tricky @QHarr?